# Im getting a "Oracle Partial Multibyte Character" error while Extraction on TABLEAU

Tags: oracle, tableau-api

I have connected Tableau to an Oracle database. I have two custom SQL on Tableau with an Inner join. The live extract works alrite but when I try to get an extract from Tableau I am getting the following error: 
"Oracle Database error 29275:ORA-29275: Partial Multibyte Character"
Please help me.

Comment: Don't know Tableau but sounds like you have something pulling a limited number of bytes rather than characters and it's happening to fall in the middle of a multibyte character. Do you have options to specify the character set in Tableau? {Although it sounds like [it has to be UTF8](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/Error-ORA-29275-partial-multibyte-character-When-Extracting-or-Viewing-Data?lang=en-us); so what are your database and national character sets?)